# Installing Windows 8 next to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning, multi-boot

Is it possible to install Windows 8 without reformatting the entire hard drive?

I have a machine running only Ubuntu 12.04, and I want to install Windows 8 and dual-boot the two. Does Windows 8 allow you to to install it in a pre-made partition or does it force you to reformat the entire hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only Reformat/erase that particular partition, not entire disk.

[image]
There are chances that it will mess up boot-loader and you will have to repair it.

But Before you start, make a backup of your most necessary data, you're going to be formatting drives and installing OS, so anything could go wrong.

Comment: Great, thanks! Glad to hear that Microsoft finally added this feature.

Comment: For anyone finding this from Google, I did install Windows 8 in its own partition, and it did preserve my other partitions.